# PHP Foreach Associative Array Loop for Sendy API

Tags: php, api, associative-array

I always struggle with loops and in particular associative arrays is still new to me and trying to get past it. I am trying to setup a form to insert multiple emails at once into our sendy email list through the use of their api. I am successful in inserting the first email into the list, but the remaining emails get lost. Your help is greatly appreciated!

PHP Below:

```
<?php 
require('sendyLibrary.php');
$sendy = new SendyLibrary('3');
$email = $_POST['email'];

//$textareaContents = str_replace("\r", ',', $email);
$multipleEmails = explode("\r", $email);
foreach($multipleEmails as $key => $finalEmail) {
    $sendy->subscribe(array(
        'email' => $finalEmail
    ));
    echo 'email: ' . $finalEmail .'<br/>';
}?>
```

Response from POST method:

```
email   sam@testing.com samg@testing.com samgo@testing.com samgol@testing.com samgolu@testing.com
```

Source from POST method:

```
email=sam%40testing.com%0D%0Asamg%40testing.com%0D%0Asamgo%40testing.com%0D%0Asamgol%40testing.com%0D%0Asamgolu%40testing.com
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: are you sure explode is working? can you show us `var_dump($multipleEmails);`

Comment: @Richie. Here is the var_dump array (size=5)
  0 => string 'sam@testing.com' (length=15)
  1 => string '
samg@testing.com' (length=17)
  2 => string '
samgo@testing.com' (length=18)
  3 => string '
samgol@testing.com' (length=19)
  4 => string '
samgolu@testing.com' (length=20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a `\r\n` inbetween all of the emails. I assume the subscribe method is throwing them out because when you explode the array on `\r` then you will have new lines on all the remaining emails. Looking like:

```
array("email1@testing.com", 
      "\nemail2@testing.com", 
      "\nemail3@testing.com");
```

You should explode the tring on `\r\n` like so:

```
$multipleEmails = explode("\r\n", $email);
```

The other option would be to fix the code that sends the POST to provide a better delimited string..